# Updating from ios6 to ios7 push notification stopped working

Tags: ios

I have some issues on push notification on IOS6 and IOS7 in ipad. Previously in IOS6 push notifications were working fine. After updating to IOS7 it is not consistent. Sometimes i am getting notifications and sometimes not. I have a messaging ipad app. From server side it is all fine but I do not receive any notfication on iOS6 & IOS7. 
  Even for other apps like facebook also not getting notifications.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your iphone uuid

Comment: It is an Ipad app. I have checked the uuid on ipad it is fine. It was working fine on ios 6. After updating ipad to ios7 notifications stopped working. This is same for other apps also in ios 7

Answer (score 1):

Did you kill your app with the app switcher?
Since ios7 killed apps do not receive push notifications.
See my answer here: [Silent push is not working when app is killed from app switcher in ios7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709540/silent-push-is-not-working-when-app-is-killed-from-app-switcher-in-ios7/21711343#21711343)