# Silent push is not working when app is killed from app switcher in ios7

Tags: ios

I am trying to send my updated location to a server whenever I receive a `push` notification.

I am able to receive a `push` notification when I killed my app from switcher but my

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler
```

delegate method is not called.

I have spent five days resolving this issue without success. Please, if anybody has any idea about this that would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does your app support the remote-notification background mode?

Comment: How do you identify that delegate is not called?

Comment: yes i have set remote-notification in info.plist. I am confused that silent push actually works or not when i kill my app from app switcher .

Comment: @volkiam..I have created a local notification in application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler delegate method. it show local notification on sending push when my app is in background and running but not when i close my app from switcher.

Answer (score 3):

Since ios7 apps which are killed from switcher do not receive push notifications.
Documentation isn't clear about this, but apple support confirmed this.
You can see the answer from apple support here:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/925788#925788

another reference:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/873265#873265